# On which Stack Exchange site should I post subjective questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I just got a question closed because it was rendered subjective by the moderators. The question is important to me and I believe other people would benefit. So, I ask the following non subjective question: on which site of the Stack Exchange ecosystem should I post [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12181752/which-cross-platform-text-editor-to-use) question?

Comment: Well, nowhere. Also, the answer is "Sublime Text 2" ;)

Answer (score 11):

### None of them.

The Stack exchange is **not** the place for subjective questions.

That is what chat is for.

Comment: At least, not *that* kind of subjective question.

Comment: @NicolBolas what other kind is there?

Comment: [See here for reference](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)

Comment: Well, on English it's probably ok to ask whether I should end sentences with one space or two, even though there is no 100% correct answer other than "it depends." I assume that one's a duplicate so, technically, it wouldn't be ok to ask. But you get my drift.

Comment: @AaronBertrand true true.